# XSLT merging and matching values

Tags: xml, database, xslt

I'm have a project that seems to have moved someway out of my comfort zone and requires some (advanced?) XSL processing.

I have the following two example XML documents:

**Doc1**

```
<instance>
    <InfBy1>Dr Phibes</InfBy1>
    <InfBy2>Dr X</InfBy2>
    <InfBy3>Dr Chivago</InfBy3>
</instance>
```

**Doc2**

```
KB_XMod_Modules>
    <Physician>Dr Phibes</Physician>
    <XModID>60</XModID>
</KB_XMod_Modules>
<KB_XMod_Modules>
    <Physician>Dr X</Physician>
    <XModID>61</XModID>
</KB_XMod_Modules>
<KB_XMod_Modules>
    <Physician>Dr Chivago</Physician>
    <XModID>62</XModID>
</KB_XMod_Modules>
```

I have to grab the XModID value from Doc2 and match it with the associated name (value) in Doc1. One extra complication however is that this is creating records to load into a database so in my scenario Dr Phibes is within `<InfBy1>` but in another record he may be in say `<InfBy3>`. Anyway, the desired output would be:

```
<InfBy1>
    <items>
        <item>
            <label>Dr Phibes</label>
            <value>60</value>
        </item>
    </items>
</InfBy1>
<InfBy2>
    <items>
        <item>
            <label>Dr X</label>
            <value>61</value>
        </item>
    </items>
</InfBy2>
<InfBy3>
    <items>
        <item>
            <label>Dr Chivago</label>
            <value>62</value>
        </item>
    </items>
</InfBy3>
```

Any ideas really appreciated...

Thanks,

Will

Comment: You wrote _"in my scenario Dr Phibes is within but in another record"_. Do you mean that there are not unique values in Doc1?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution and for its explanation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPhysByName" match="KB_XMod_Modules"
          use="Physician"/>

 <my:doc2>
    <KB_XMod_Modules>
        <Physician>Dr Phibes</Physician>
        <XModID>60</XModID>
    </KB_XMod_Modules>
    <KB_XMod_Modules>
        <Physician>Dr X</Physician>
        <XModID>61</XModID>
    </KB_XMod_Modules>
    <KB_XMod_Modules>
        <Physician>Dr Chivago</Physician>
        <XModID>62</XModID>
    </KB_XMod_Modules>
 </my:doc2>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <result>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </result>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'InfBy')]">
  <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
   <xsl:variable name="vMod" select="key('kPhysByName', $vCur)"/>
   <xsl:copy>
    <items>
     <item>
      <label><xsl:value-of select="$vMod/Physician"/></label>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="$vMod/XModID"/></value>
     </item>
    </items>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the first of the provided XML documents** (it contains the second embedded -- just for convenience):

```
<instance>
    <InfBy1>Dr Phibes</InfBy1>
    <InfBy2>Dr X</InfBy2>
    <InfBy3>Dr Chivago</InfBy3>
</instance>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<result xmlns:my="my:my">
    <items>
        <item>
            <label>Dr Phibes</label>
            <value>60</value>
        </item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>
            <label>Dr X</label>
            <value>61</value>
        </item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>
            <label>Dr Chivago</label>
            <value>62</value>
        </item>
    </items>
</result>
```

**Explanation**:

This transformation is pretty straight-forward. We are using keys for convenience and we are embedding the second document into the XSLT stylesheet for the same reason. **In a practical application the second document will be stand-alone and the only change required (except removing it from the stylesheet) will be to replace**:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
```

with:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="document('someURL')">
```

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks - my error. I hadn't marked the tag I referred to as code so it didn't show up. To answer your question, the tag names are replicated throughout each record and in that sense, aren't unique

Comment: @Dimitre Thanks for your suggestion and explanation. At the moment I'm simply getting an empty `<result xmlns:my="my:my"></results>` but I'll progress and see what I get back...

Comment: @Willb: I always test my answers -- and this works. If you don't get the reported result the reason may be that you changed the transformation or that you changed the XML docu

Comment: @Willb: I'm still in doubt wether there is the need to get the disctict doctors' names before dereference the id.

Comment: @Dimitre: Perhaps I'm missing something fairly fundamental but this isn't working for me. I've created a Doc1.xml with the `<infby#>` stucture exactly as described in my initial question. I've also created a transform.xsl document with your code unchanged. I'm using dreamweaver to apply the xsl to the xml and still get an empty output with just the `<result xmlns:my="my:my"></results>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Willb: Yes, the thing you have missed is to change the code of my solution -- read the end of the explanation.